# How to limit image size for the entire website ? But without editing the post (css/plugin?!)

Tags: plugins, css, images

I have a post here:

http://www.food101.co.il/?p=5993

Where the image is overlapping the sidebar.  I wish to shrink the image, but I want something that will do this without me editing the post (why? because the author is not me - and I want an automated system)

Is there a plugin or a CSS solution that can do this? (as cross browser as possible?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix via CSS would be using [max-width property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_max-width.asp) to style images inside posts. Unfortunately it is very unreliable in Internet Explorer.

`.entry img { max-width:500px !important; }`

Also in your specific case image has size defined with inline style and it interferes.

Plugin method would involve scanning and changing posts content on the fly, which would probably bring in performance issues, etc.

In my opinion it is better to fix such things consistently on content level. If you have no authority to edit posts show the issue to person who has.

Comment: Thank you Rarst.  I used it and it works (at least for chrome).  I understand your suggestion but in this particular case this is not applicable.  Thanks again! Tal

Comment: Hello Rarst - for some reason this doesn't work for me here:  http://www.food101.co.il/?p=6042

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `$GLOBALS['content_width'] = 500;` to your theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Ajax Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) plugin. Once you re-specify the maximum image width size default under Settings > Media, this plugin will regenerate the thumbnails when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {max-width:98%; height: auto;}
```

use this in your stylesheet.